# Add non-included header file to up-to-date check in Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and I write code in C++.

There always was one problem with the `#define` settings in header files. The first approach is to place settings in multiple header files corresponding to specific source files. This approach is OK for minimal rebuild but the main disadvantage is that settings are stored in multiple files.

Another approach is to store all defines in one `config.h` file and to include it to all source files. It is much easier to configure but all files including `config.h` will be recompiled each time I change a setting.

So I decided to use the third approach. All settings are stored in `config.h` (one per project) and have a special comment line before them with the relative path of the exact header file, like this:

```
// in:core/net/http.h
// some http setting
#define CFG_SOME_HTTP_OPTION

// in:core/net/dns.h
// some dns setting
#define CFG_SOME_DNS_OPTION
```

But `config.h` itself is not included by any source file. Instead it is parsed by pre-build script, which builds a code with all defines for each header file mentioned in the `config.h`. Then a check is made if this code differs from the code already presented in the specific header and the replacement is made only if the code differs. This approach keeps the advantages of two previous approaches because all settings are still in one header file but only those files whose settings were changed are to be rebuilded.

I wrote this script and everything works perfectly except one thing. The `config.h` is a part of the project but is not included in any source file. That's why Visual Studio does not even run my pre-build script because of up-to-date check: if changes are made only in `config.h` it still thinks that project is up-to-date.

How can I solve this? The easiest approach is to create special source file including `config.h` for each project, but maybe there is another method to force build process if only `config.h` is modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Just changed `Item Type` to `C/C++ compiler` instead of the `C/C++ header` in the `config.h` properties.